# Proof that larger open balls contain the closure of smaller ones

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Easy question, but I can't think of the correct way to do it. If I have a sequence of open balls, $\{U_m\}$, the balls of radius $\frac{1}{m}$ about zero, how do I show that $\overline{U_m}$ is contained in $U_{m-1}$?

Comment: Note that using the usual distance on $\mathbb{Z}$, we may have $\overline{U_m} = U_{m-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any points in $x\in\overline{U}_m$ and show that it is in $U_{m-1}$. 
We have $$x\in\overline{U}_m\iff \|x-0\|=\|x\| \leq \frac{1}{m}$$ 
and 
$$x \in U_{m-1}\iff \|x-0\|=\|x\|<\frac{1}{m-1}$$
Can you conclude?

Note: I used a norm, but note that you can easily replace the norm by a metric and apply the same principle.

Comment: Oh, duh! I suppose I was somehow trying to think about the closed balls as being "the smallest closed set" containing the open ball, which is clearly the wrong way to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Anthony you're welcome. If you have the chance to have a metric (or even better, a norm) often it is worth to use it :).